# how to suppress line id wise data in sql or crystal report

Tags: mysql, sql, crystal-reports-2010

I have this query.

```
   (CASE 
        WHEN (T1."LineNum") = '0' THEN (T1."U_UNE_BLDT"[enter image description here][1])
    END AS "1", 
    CASE 
        WHEN (T1."LineNum") = '1' THEN T1."U_UNE_BLDT"
    END AS "2", 
    CASE 
        WHEN (T1."LineNum") = '2' THEN T1."U_UNE_BLDT"
    END AS "3",
```

Expected output [image: Output]

Comment: imaged added inline

Comment: @DanishS.A. please explain. Do you want to hide first row of each SamplingPoint? And show us more code, otherwise you can not give you any helpful advice